# Difference between EngineConfig and DesignConfig in BIRT

Tags: birt

I have a difficulty in understanding when to use EngineConfig and DesignConfig to configure the BIRT engine? Please give me proper difference so that I can clearly understand the use of both classes(i.e EngineConfig and DesignConfig).

Answer (score 0):

One diff that I found out during my work was 
EngineConfig helps us to operate on the existing rptdesign and
DesignConfig helps to create a new rptdesign on the fly and generate report out of it. It has so m any api to create a table, grid , charts etc.

Comment: Hey thanks. I also got the same difference while doing my work.